# javascript iterate through array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
levelinfoarray["test"] = new Array(16,20,4,5,"Test level");
levelinfoarray[1] = new Array(29,25,17,13,"Introduction");
levelinfoarray[2] = new Array(16,24,6,4,"Counting...");
levelinfoarray[3] = new Array(16,20,4,5,"Where am I going?");
...
```

I want to iterate through the array and get the level number and level description like this

```
Test) Test level
1) Introduction
2) Counting...
3) Where am I going?
...
```

I have tried a for loop and a forEach, but both only give me the numbered entries.  How would I get the "test" entry?

Comment: With JavaScript arrays, it's really not practical to mix numeric and non-numeric keys. Arrays are all about the numerically indexed properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an array has non-numeric keys, it's actually an object. Use `for...in`

```
for (key in levelinfoarray) {
    if (levelinfoarray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key+') '+levelinfoarray[key][4]);
    }
}
```

P.S. don't use `new Array`, use array literals:

```
levelinfoarray["test"] = [16,20,4,5,"Test level"];
```

Comment: This will work, but it's important to note that the order of property traversal is undefined.

Comment: An array is always an object. With _strings_ as keys

Comment: This works great, it puts the test array at the end of the list, which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(levelinfoarray) // => ["1", "2", "3", "test"]
```

To iterate:

```
Object.keys(levelinfoarray).forEach(function(key) {console.log(key)});
```

You'll have to polyfill `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach`, if you want to support older browsers.